# How to Handle push notification when sent to multiple device but some them are failed

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send fcm push notifications to android and ios app. I am using this code to send

```
let message = {
    registration_ids: firebaseId, // this is the array of tokens
        collapse_key: 'something',
        data: {
          type: data.type,
          title: data.title,
          body : data.body,
          notificationId: something
        },
  }; 
  fcm.send(message, (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        resolve(false);
      } else {
        console.log("Notification Android Sent Successfully");
        console.log(response);
      }
});
```

Now what I want if some notifications are failed then I want to send them SMS. but I got a response like this form the fcm server in case of success or failure.

> Notification Android Sent Successfully
> {"multicast_id":7535512435227354255,"success":2,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1610622370449056%d0bd483c86f03759"},{"message_id":"0:1610622370449058%d0bd483c86f03759"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

now how will I know which device did not get the notification as we can see there 1 failure from 3 device
so i can send SMS to that device

Comment: Brother actually i was logged out for some days that why there is no reply, but this you answer did not helped me i know that third was failed but how to get that token for which it failed right no i have to match response erro index to firebaseids array to figure out

Answer (score 0):

The `results` in the response you get contains the result for each token, in the same order in which you specified them,

So in your example, the message was successfully sent to the first two tokens, while the third token was unknown. You'll want to remove that last token from your database to prevent trying to send messages to it in the future.

Comment: Yes we can see that third notification failed but it would be better if they also return failed notification reg_id like error, so we can just filter out the failed reg_id, but now in this case i have match the index for the reg_id which are getting error, then from these index i will get firebaseIds array, then after query db i will get the number then i will send the notifiction

Comment: While it's valid to wish the API worked differently, the way it works already allows you to determine which tokens succeeded and which ones failed, which is what you asked. In your example the third token in `firebaseId, // this is the array of tokens` is invalid.